# Python3.4 : Matching and returning list values

Tags: list, loops, python-3.x

I have opened a text file in Python which has thousands of lines.  I need to search each line to see if it contains 1 of many different specified values.  I then need to return the specific value and the corresponding line that contains that value.

```
q1 = open('/home/lost/StockRec/StockIndex/edgar.full-index.2015.QTR1.master.idx', 'r')

list = ['1341234', '12341234', '4563456', '12341234', '6896786', '2727638']

for line in q1:
    for listValue in list:
        if listValue in line:
            print(listValue, line)
```

I know this code is wrong.  I need to search each line in q1 for each of the specific values in the list.  I need to then print the specific list value and the line containing that value.

Comment: What do you mean by "return"? It doesn't look like this code is inside a function, so using `return` would only cause an error.

Comment: sorry... not the best term to use, edited to print :-)

Comment: “I know this code is wrong.” – Why? What’s wrong with it?

Comment: It isn't returning a the specific value from the list and the line containing that value... It is returning all listValues and all lines

Answer (score 0):

Unless your file is already somehow separated into lines, it looks like you will have to first split the file into lines when you import it. Right now it is returning all of it because q1 is only one line.

Look for some identifying information in your file such as new line characters ('\n') or if each line starts with a specific character.
so once you open the file you will include:

`q1.split('your identifying character here')`

That will split the copy of your file then you can perform the loops that you have already written